# Which different between ExecuteCore / Execute / Initialize on Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[ControllerBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.aspx) in ASP.NET MVC contains three methods:

- [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.execute.aspx)
- [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.initialize.aspx)
- [ExecuteCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.executecore.aspx)

I couldn't find a lot of information about these. Just advice to use [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.initialize.aspx) instead of [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.execute.aspx). Could anybody know the purposes of these methods? And in which case they should be used according to good practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Execute` method is the one that comes from the `IController` interface and that all controllers posses. In the default implementation (`ControllerBase`) the Execute method first calls the `Initialize` method and then the `ExecuteCore` method. The Initialize method is where the context becomes available. This is the earliest method in the pipeline execution where you can access the HttpContext related stuff. For example if you attempt to access it in a controller's constructor you will get a NRE. The `ExecuteCore` method is responsible for loading the TempData, finding and executing the correct action to execute given the `action` route data value and finally saving the TempData.

Comment: So if I get correct `Execute` manages all other methods. 'Initialize' sets `ControllerContext`, `ExecuteCore` sets TempData. I should avoid to overtiring first.. can change second as I want to set new culture and so on.. and use third if I want access to temp data. If I want to predefine some information (grab data from Session and so on) I should use `OnActionExecuting`. And finally for some finalization action I should use `OnActionExecuted`. Thanks.